# Design advice for executing sequence of ros msg interactions

Tags: ros, callback, spinonce, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling with a good design for nodes that when receiving a callback must perform a sequence of interactions with one or more other ros nodes.

So far I ended up mixing spin and spinOnce but something tells me that this is far from optimal.
Here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
void actionCallback() {

    // want to write some logic in sequential style,
    // but the sequence involves multiple ros message send/receive:
    result1 = rosService1();
    result2 = rosService2();
    result3 = waitForSomeMessageOnTopic();

    // ...
}

Result rosService1() {

    // This my attempt of simulating a synchronous call to a ros service
    ... call service 1

    while (response from service1 not received) {
        spin_once();
        ... sleep a bit
    }

    ... return result from service1 response
}

int main() {
    ...
    startActionServer();
    spin();
}
```

I guess this design challenge has some better well-proven solutions. Please advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274903/design-advice-for-executing-sequence-of-ros-msg-interactions/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So far I ended up mixing spin and spinOnce but something tells me that this is far from optimal.

Yes. Please try to not do that.

> I am struggling with a good design for nodes that when receiving a callback must perform a sequence of interactions with one or more other ros nodes. [..] I guess this design challenge has some better well-proven solutions

I would say this is *coordination*, for which one of the accepted approaches is using state machines (or state charts, behaviour trees, or similar formalisms). State machines are really well suited for modelling "sequence[s] of interactions" based on *state* (ie: events).

See #q273811 for a similar question (and the answer to that).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-11-04**:\

> > Yes. Please try to not do that

But really, why not? I find it easy to read and debug.
Is there anything technically wrong with calling spin_once in a callback, using it as a "yield"?
I am using SMACH for coordination at the higher "task" level, but at this level, SMACH seems like overkill.